# How to count matches for a named capture group in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

I have a Perl command I cobbled together that runs a regex find and replace on a file. It works great, but has the unfortunate side effect of "modifying" the file even if the resulting file is identical. This makes sense since it is replacing the matches with themselves. We cant have this because the result is part of a `make` pipeline and causes an entire rebuild every time it is run.

I would now like to run a command to get a count of matches for a specific named capture group so that I can test if anything needs to be replaced before actually running the first command.

The command is executed though `bash` with some bash variables: `perl -0777 -i -pe '$cnt=0;s{('$PASSTHROUGH'|'$REPLACE')}{$+{PASSTHROUGH}?$+{PASSTHROUGH}:(++$cnt,'$REPLACEMENT')")}peg; END{print "$cnt\n"}'`

Again, this works great and gives me the number of actual replacements made since `$cnt` is only incremented in the `else` branch of the ternary operator. If I were to run a match for only the `$REPLACE` pattern I would not get the correct number since often it would match things in the `$PASSTHROUGH` group.

I suspect there is a way to retrieve the count of a specific group, but I don't know Perl or the terminology, so I am struggling to find an answer to how I can alter this command to *not* do a replace, but rather simply count the matches to the `$REPLACE` sub-pattern only. It is a named group: `(?<REPLACE>some-regex-pattern)`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with passthrough, it matches but doesn't change anything? Why match at all then?
If that's correct, you can just remove PASSTHROUGH on the left side and use the return value of s{SEARCH}{REPLACE}

Comment: the special map %+ is reset each time regex matches so there is no other way to get count than using `++$cnt` maybe `\K` can be used to avoid replacing passthrough matches, for example `((?:'$PASSTHROUGH'\K)|'$REPLACE')`

Comment: @Eily because `$REPLACE` would otherwise match things matched by `$PASSTHROUGH`. `$PASSTHROUGH` is a rather complex pattern made of several other subpatterns and uses recursion and it is not possible to my knowledge to do what I need without it.

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul my problem is not with the count per se `++$cnt` is working fine for me. I need a way of getting `$cnt` without actually modifying the file. I will look into `\K`. Thank you.

Comment: @BradAllred, in the code you've shown we can't see the file is modified maybe there's the `-i` option can be removed to not modify the file

Comment: @BradAllred maybe a negative look-ahead assertion can help, `(?!THAT)(THIS)` will check that the current position can't match `THAT` before it even tries matching `THIS`, so this effictively gives the possibility to match "THIS but not THAT".

Comment: @Eily That is the first thing I tried. Unfortunately negative look arounds are limited. I no longer recall which advanced feature Perl complained about, but the error was something along the lines of `X cannot be used with negative look around`. I suspect the recursion.

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul I will try removing the -i. If it is that simple I will feel silly :)

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul using `\K` on the `$PASSTHROUGH` didn't work. It is now making bizzare substitutions that are duplicating things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT after question update

- `-0777` means the whole file is read once (input record separator undef)
- `-i` : edit file inplace (like sed -i), must be removed to avoid to modify file
- `-p` : prints lines

following command should just print the number of matches

```
perl -0777 -ne '$cnt=@a=m{('$PASSTHROUGH'(*SKIP)(?!)|'$REPLACE')}pg;print "$cnt\n"'
```

it is done differently :

- the principle of pattern alternation is to match first what should fail to keep what we want
- `(*SKIP)` : is a backtracking control verb which prevent regex engine to backtrack after match fail, that's what is done normally
- `(?!)` : is the same as `(*FAIL)`

Comment: I will update the question with the complete Perl command. My apologies.

Comment: ok note that the files were always modified because of the `print "$cnt"` at the end which is written in file

Comment: I'm not so sure about that. the files don't contain anything of the sort after running this. only the replacements made by the pattern. git shows no other changes and such changes would cause compile errors.

Comment: I've updated with the missing switches. I believe the `-0777` is somehow to process the entire file rather than line-by-line.

Comment: Thank you so much. I believe this works! allow me to run some more tests before I accept. Would you mind explaining the `-ne` options?

Comment: `perl -h` can give information on switchs similar to sed,  `-e` is followed by perl expression,  `-n` loops over input without printing, otherwise if there's many files after perl program it could be useful to print current file 'print $ARGV'

Comment: little change which is important, because not tested, `$cnt=@a=m{..}g` because `m{..}g` must be evaled in array context to give all matches and `@a` in scalar context to give number of matches